# Is there a difference between $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(x)^2$?

Tags: trigonometry, notation

Is there a difference between these? Or are they the same?

If they're the same, then why does $\sin^2(x)$ seem like its used more often?

Comment: Mmmm.... style. mostly.  "sin" seems like the meat and body of the concept whereas (x) is just the input.  It seems to make more sense to put modifications closer the the "sin".  Or it does to me.  $\sin(x)^2$ looks like the power is trying to modify the (x) and I have to look twice to verify that it is actually the [sin(x)] that is being squared.  Or so it looks to me...

Answer (score 1):

No difference, just convention.

Answer (score 1):

The two possibilities are
$$
P_1 = \big(\sin x\big)^2
\\
P_2 = \sin\big(x^2\big)
$$
The convention (which confuses beginners) is
$$
\sin^2 x = P_1
$$
If you write
$$
\sin x^2
$$
or even
$$
\sin(x)^2
$$
we cannot tell which you mean.

Answer (score 1):

No difference,

$\sin^2(x) = \sin(x)^2 = (\sin(x))^2$

$\sin^2(x)$ is used more often because it's easier to write especially dealing with complex equations.