# What is the difference between $2\sin(x)$ and $\sin(2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1712210/276997), I saw that there was no difference between $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(x)^2$.

However, I am curious what's the difference between $2\sin(x)$ and $\sin(2x)$?

Comment: $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$

Comment: Besides what Moo commented, try to see the difference when you take $\;x=\frac\pi2\;$ .

Comment: Qualitatively, $\sin 2x$ has amplitude $1$ and period $\pi$, whereas $2\sin x$ has amplitude $2$ and period $2\pi$.

Comment: There is no difference between $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(x)^2$ simply because we *define* $\sin^2(x)$ as what you get squaring $\sin(x)$; this is not an identity or anything deep, but notation.

Comment: $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(x)^2$ are analogous to $(\sin\cdot2)(x)$ and $\sin(x)\cdot2$, whereas $2\sin(x)$ and $\sin(2x)$ are probably analogous to $\sin(x)^2$ and $\sin(x^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that aside from that fact that
$$\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x,$$
the difference should be patently clear once you have the graphs.
[image]

Notice that $2\sin x$ means take the value $\sin x$ and double it. Where as $\sin 2x$ means take the value $x$, double it, and then apply the $\sin $ function to that value.

Also, I do not believe it is universally accepted that
$$\sin^2 (x) = \sin (x)^2,$$
since $\sin (x)^2$ can be interpreted as 
$$\sin ((x)^2).$$
For a less ambiguous case, take for example $\sin (2xy)^2$
is can easily be interpreted as 
$$\sin 4x^2y^2$$
or 
$$\sin^2 (2xy).$$
So I believe there is a difference.

For the sake of clarity, $\sin (x)^2$ should really be written as
$$(\sin x)^2$$
if you mean to convey $\sin^2 x$.

Comment: What program are you using to graph?

Comment: [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) online graphing calculator.

Answer (score 5):

$2\sin(x)$ is multiplying the $\sin$ function by 2. Whereas the $\sin(2x)$ is inputting a value of twice $x$ into the function. Note that $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) \neq 2\sin(x)$

Answer (score 2):

$2\sin x$ means first you take the sine of $x$.  Then you multiply the result by 2.

$\sin 2x$ means first you multiply $x$ by 2.  Then you take the sine of the result.

$\sin 2x$ can, and sometimes should, also be written as $\sin(2x)$.

It is **not** ok to pull constant multiples out of trig functions.

Answer (score 2):

Really,  $\sin(x) ^2 = \sin^2(x)$ only because we adopted the function notation used prior,  namely $f(x) ^2 = f^2(x)$. In most cases I still use the former to avoid confusing differentiation or iteration,  but trig functions  still use the latter. Now,  this notation only holds for powers...  When you say $2\sin(x)$ you are making a sine wave with an amplitude of $2$. When you say $\sin(2x)$ you are talking about a sine wave with twice the frequency of the standard sine wave.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ its double angle formula