# Difference in $\sin \theta ^2$ and $\sin^2\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, notation

What is difference between $\sin \theta ^2$ and $\sin ^2\theta$? What is the meaning of $\sin \theta\ \times$ $\sin \theta$?

Comment: To avoid confusion, put parentheses. Otherwise, this kind of problems. $\sin(t^2)$ vs $\sin^2(t)$

Comment: $\sin^2 \theta = (\sin \theta)^2$ but $\sin(\theta^2) \neq \sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: I upvoted to reverse a downvote which I regard as *harsh*.  The OP was asking for clarification of a definition.  This isn't the type of situation where I (for one) would expect the OP to provide background or show work.

Comment: $\sin^2(\theta)=(\sin(\theta))^2=\sin(\theta)\cdot \sin(\theta)$

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1712224) answer your question?

Comment: It is just because it is easier to write the other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are many cases where we want powers of trig functions, we define $\sin^2(x)=(\sin(x))^2$.  It doesn't have to be that way.  For more general functions, we often define $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$, which is not the same thing.  We also define $\sin^{-1}(x)$ as the inverse function of $\sin(x)$ (though many denote it $\arcsin(x)$), with the range restricted to make it a function.  By analogy with $\sin^2(x)$ it should be $\frac 1{\sin(x)}$.  The $\arcsin$ version is in accord with the usual notation of $f^{-1}(x)$ being the inverse function of $f(x)$.  Yes, it is inconsistent, but it is useful, so you need to get used to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have one question to ask that how does the angle changes when we make it sin^2 X?Does it also mean the square of perpendicular over Hypotenuse.

Comment: It doesn't change anything about the angle.  You take the sine as usual and square it.  Although we start defining $\sin x$ in terms of angles, it is better to think of it as a more general function of $x$